# How to share global data among SOME threads?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python (2.7) program which spawns batches of 100 threads. Each batch of 100 threads must have their own global lock, and their own global string. I am subclassing the `threading.Thread` module. I think for the global lock, I can just pass that in through each thread's constructor. However, I'm not sure about a global string. If I pass a string to each thread's constructor, each thread will have its own instance of the string.

I want the global variables for each batch of 100 threads to act as if they were class variables.

```
class Test(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, someString, lock):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self._someString = someString
        self._LOCK = lock

    def run(self):
        # How would I change self._someString for all 100 threads in this particular batch?

lock1 = threading.Lock()
for _ in xrange(100): Test('x1', lock1).start()

lock2 = threading.Lock()
for _ in xrange(100): Test('x2', lock2).start()
```

I tried passing the string in a dictionary:

```
lock1 = threading.Lock()
str1 = {'str':'some string'}
for _ in xrange(100): Test(str1, lock1).start()
```

But that didn't seem to work, either. It still only modified the dictionary for that particular thread.

Comment: Wouldn't it be trivial for you to test out whether the strings are the same object or not?

Comment: @DroidX86 sorry, I'm not too sure what you mean by that. I want a global variable for only the batch of 100 threads that I can alter as if it were a class variable.

Comment: Why don't you try doing just that - like you're doing for the lock - and see how that goes

Comment: @DroidX86 I did prior to posting the question. Each thread seems to have its own instance of the string as I mentioned in the last sentence. I'd like to change it in one thread, and have the changes reflect in the other 99 threads but not in other batches of 100 threads.

Comment: You can wrap the string in an object and send that object them

Comment: @DroidX86 see my edit.

Comment: Sounds like you probably replaced the dictionary instead of modifying it when you tried to modify it, but we can't tell, since you haven't shown us how you tried to modify it.

Comment: @user2357112 ah you're right, that was it. It works now. Is that the best way to achieve class-type variables for certain threads (using a dictionary)?

Comment: (I've always felt that Python could use a canonical "thing-holder" type that just holds one thing, like a first-class variable. Closure cells would do the job, if they were mutable. One-element lists usually end up being used for the role, but it's not as clear or clean as it could be.)

Comment: A dictionary isn't the usual choice if you just want to share one thing, but using some kind of shared storage object is pretty common. What that shared storage object is tends to vary by use case, but a list is typical if there's nothing else to attach a shared variable to.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the clarification and help. If you wanna post what you've said as a standalone answer, I'll gladly accept it.